# Java Doc Map interface confusing description

Tags: java

A paragraph in the description of the Map interface

> Many methods in Collections Framework interfaces are defined in terms of the equals method. For example, the specification for the containsKey(Object key) method says: "returns true if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))."

Why don't they use (key==null ? **true** : key.equals(k)) instead of  (key==null ? **k==null** : key.equals(k))?

Comment: What if the key in the map isn't `null`, ie. the map doesn't contain an entry with key `null`?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Thank you! I got it. I wasn't noticed the `key` and `k`.